# open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s) and Uncaught CurlException: 3: No URL set! thrown in base_facebook.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, curl, facebook-php-sdk

```
protected function makeRequest($url, $params, $ch=null) {
    if (!$ch) {
      $ch = curl_init();
    }

    $opts = self::$CURL_OPTS;
    if ($this->useFileUploadSupport()) {
      $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
    } else {
      $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
    }
    $opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;

    // disable the 'Expect: 100-continue' behaviour. This causes CURL to wait
    // for 2 seconds if the server does not support this header.
    if (isset($opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER])) {
      $existing_headers = $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER];
      $existing_headers[] = 'Expect:';
      $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $existing_headers;
    } else {
      $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Expect:');
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) { // CURLE_SSL_CACERT
      self::errorLog('Invalid or no certificate authority found, '.
                     'using bundled information');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
                  dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    if ($result === false) {
      $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
        'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
        'error' => array(
        'message' => curl_error($ch),
        'type' => 'CurlException',
        ),
      ));
      curl_close($ch);
      throw $e;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }
```

I have built a facebook app, but something went wrong in this piece of code of base_facebook.php.

[Whole code is here](http://pastebin.com/TnYDN7Qg). All i get everytime are this 2 errors -

1.Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/a2424901/public_html/base_facebook.php on line 802

2.Uncaught CurlException: 3: No URL set! thrown in /home/a2424901/public_html/base_facebook.php on line 814

[Here](http://pastebin.com/1aZiBDbe) is the code of my facebook app i.e.(index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, non-obvious error message.
But it means, that [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) returns empty value:

> File() is not within the allowed path(s)...

Make sure, that the file passed to realpath() function really exists in the specified path.

Other exceptions in your example were caused by this problem. 
By the way, it's good practice to wrap all weak spots (in your example - Facebook API calls) in try-catch blocks.